# How to Prevent DynamoDB Table Creation Unless Under Certain Capacity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

Is there a way to allow creation of a resource like a DynamoDB table only if the table to be created was PAY_PER_REQUEST or was provisioned with capacity below a certain amount?

I initially looked at [IAM condition keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazondynamodb.html#amazondynamodb-table), but they appear to only be available for interactions with the table data operations (scan, update, put operations etc.) but not creation operations for the table.

Alternatively, are there ways to **reduce** service quotas for an account?

Ideally, I'm wondering if it is possible to scope down the ability to create DynamoDB table resources beyond a certain capacity and I’m not sure how to do it proactively instead of retroactively processing CloudTrail logs or listing existing table properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AWS Config**

You can use AWS Config to retrospectively query AWS resources and their properties, and then determine if they are compliant or not. There are [rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/managed-rules-by-aws-config.html) already available out of the box, but I can't see one which matches your use case. You will need to then write a Lambda function to implement this yourself. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config_develop-rules_nodejs-sample.html) is an example.

After your rule is working you can either create a remediation action to

- Delete the Table
- Scale the Table Down
- Send a Notification
- Adjust Autoscaling (i.e. reduce max)

**AWS Budgets**
(My Preference)
For determining if an account is using too much DynamoDB, probably the easiest is to setup a budget for the DynamoDB Service. That would have a couple of benefits:

- **Auto-Scaling:** Developers would be free to use high amounts of capacity (such as load tests) for short periods of time.
- **Potentially Cheaper:** what I have found is that if you put restrictions on projects often developers will allocate 100% of the maximum, as opposed to using only what they need, in fear for another developer coming along and taking all the capacity.

Just like before with AWS Config you can setup Billing Alarms to take action and notify developers that they are using too much DynamoDB, also when the Budget is at 50%, 80% ... and so on.

**CloudWatch**

You could also create CloudWatch Alarms as well for certain DynamoDB metrics, looking at the capacity which has been used and again responding to excessive use.

**Conclusion**

You have a lot of flexibility how to approach this, so make sure you have gathered up your requirements and then the appropriate response will be easier to see. AWS Config requires a bit more work than budgets so if you can get what you want out of Budgets I would do that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! It sounds like most of the possible approaches here are reactive (after the API calls to create the table have already been made). I looked more at AWS Config & while it makes sense from the compliance and reporting perspective I'm worried it would take too long to address the issue (of table creation).

Do you think there's a benefit of AWS Config over simply running a regularly scheduled Lambda function each minute and iterating over the current DynamoDB tables and remediating them manually if they're in a bad state?

Comment: AWS Config checks can be configured to run on resource change so no need to setup a polling Lambda, (that is often one of the wrong answers in the multi choice cert tests). It gives you traceability and auditing as well. It's on a per resource basis that is why I recommend budgets for your use case, as this will be across tables as well as allow for small periods of larger use. You can combine that with AWS Config for a max allowable capacity as well.